# CSS multi line Labels align

Tags: css

How could I align 2 labels with bottom alignments. if one label has multiple lines, the label next to it will appear from the top. could I align it to the bottom?

http://jsfiddle.net/ghkJC/3/

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="label">labl 1:</div>
  <div class="value">Some text</div>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>

<div class="field">
  <div class="label">this is a really really long label:</div>
  <div class="value">right after":" from previous label</div>
  <br />
</div>

.label {
    background: purple;
    float: left;      
    width: 100px;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: 500px;

}

.value {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;

}
```

many thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some options for you:

1. Use `display:inline-block`:

   ```
   .label {
       background: purple;
       width: 100px;
       display: inline-block;
   }
   .value {
       background: red;
       width: 300px;
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: bottom;
   }
   ```

   **[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghkJC/4/)**
2. Use `display:table` and `table-cell`

   ```
   .field {
       display: table;
   }
   .label,.value{
       display: table-cell;
   }
   .label {
       background: purple;
       min-width: 100px;
   }
   .value {
       background: red;
       width: 100%;
       vertical-align: bottom;
   }
   ```

   **[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghkJC/8/)**
3. Use `position:absolute`

   ```
   .field {
       position: relative;
   }   
   .label {
       background: purple;
       width: 100px;
   }
   .value {
       background: red;
       width: 300px;
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
   }
   ```

   **[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghkJC/6/)**

**Note:** first two options won't work in IE < 8 (without some hacks)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really helpful. I think the 1st one is the option I am looking for. but if it not support the IE<8, it may become a problem

Comment: @WilliamWEI fortunately there's a hack for that one to work in IE7, see this http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/ghkJC/10/

Comment: @WilliamWEI also I see you're new here, welcome! if you haven't please read [this info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on what to do when you get an answer to your question

Comment: I wanted to MIDDLE align my value, and this worked great. Adjusted: http://jsfiddle.net/prrstn/64NmT/

Answer (score 0):

Use this example in this example css multi line label is assign

```
label {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
input {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3yRQ/)

**CSS**

```
.label {
        background: purple;
        float: left;      
        width: 100px;
        display: inline;
        vertical-align: 500px;

}

.value {
        background: red;
        width: 300px;
        float: right;
}
#bor
{
    line-height:40px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="label">labl 1:</div>
        <div class="value">Some text</div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="label">this is a really really long label:</div>
        <div id="bor" class="value">right after":" from previous label</div>
        <br />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is it possible that not set an inline-height, just make the "right after":" from previous label" apear lower? so the text of that label will appear right after the "long label:"

Comment: I mean without change the line-height. let the second red label start in a lower position so that the text of the label will be in same line with "really long label:". Sorry I couldn't upload the picture to explain my thought.